# Show/Hide Password in Two Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I' trying to build a form in which the users can change the values of two password inputs, one for a password and a second one to verify the password.

So in order to make the user aware of what he types and to make sure both of his/her password match with one another and tried to implemente a method in which he can just check a checkbox to show his password.

The current javascript method works with just one input but I would like to have it working with both input and not just one. I would like as well to show the password of both input without having to check their own corresponding checkbox(for example if a check one checkbox it should display text in both inputs).

This is the current javascript method that I have:

```js
// First Code //
function addEvent (el, event, callback) {
  if ('addEventListener' in el) {                  
    el.addEventListener(event, callback, false);   
  } else {                                         
    el['e' + event + callback] = callback;         
    el[event + callback] = function () {
      el['e' + event + callback](window.event);
    };
    el.attachEvent('on' + event, el[event + callback]);
  }
}


function removeEvent(el, event, callback) {
  if ('removeEventListener' in el) {                      
    el.removeEventListener(event, callback, false);      
  } else {                                               
    el.detachEvent('on' + event, el[event + callback]);  
    el[event + callback] = null;
    el['e' + event + callback] = null;
  }
}


// Second Code //
(function() {

  var pwd = document.getElementById('password');
  var chk = document.getElementById('showpass'); 

  addEvent(chk, 'change', function(e) {       
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;   
    try {                                     
      if (target.checked) {                  
        password.type = 'text';              
      } else {                               
        password.type = 'password';          
      }
    } catch(error) {                            
      alert('This browser cannot switch type'); 
    }
  });

}());
```

```html
<!-- First Password -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" id="showpass"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Password -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="" id="password2" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" id="showpass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to set the visibility by checking one checkbox itself, then why is a second checkbox necessary in the first place?

Comment: Side note, the id attribute is designed to be unique per element. But you have  id="showpass" on both checkboxes

Comment: pretty much just because of the look. I'm using Bootstrap and it would look awkward just having a single checkbox...that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of both inputs at once:

```
var pwd = document.getElementById('password');
var confirm = document.getElementById('password2');

...

if (target.checked) {                  
    pwd.type = 'text';              
    confirm.type = 'text';              
} else {                               
    pwd.type = 'password';         
    confirm.type = 'password';              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a little fiddle to toggle the password type.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/321232/

**JS**

```
var $vp = $('.vp');
$vp.on('click', function() {
    var $target = $(this).siblings('input[name*="password"]');
  if ($target.attr('type') == "password") {$target.attr('type','text');}
  else {$target.attr('type','password');}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:100%;float:left;margin:0 0 16px 0;">
    <p>Password 1</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" val="" />
    <span class="vp">View password</span>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;float:left;margin:0 0 16px 0;">
    <p>Password 2</p>
    <input type="password" name="password2" val="" />
    <span class="vp">View password</span>
</div>
```

The function looks for the click event of the span "vp" and get's its sibling input element, checks the type attribute and toggles it to and from text/password. The name of the inputs must contain "password" (in lowercase).